# Setting 'fields' parameter in Google Drive API using r googledrive

Tags: r, google-drive-api

I am using the R googledrive package to pull details for around 1,000 files from the Google Drive API into a shiny app.

The function `drive_find(q = "parents in 'xxx'")` successfully returns those details but is very slow - there are over 2000 fields. In R the first two fields returned are called 'id' and 'name' which is all I want.

However, `drive_find(q = "parents in 'xxx'", fields = 'id')` returns a 400 error as the field called id is not found.

Any suggestions please? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `files/id, files/name` as your fields.

Tested using the API explorer.

[image]

Comment: Thank you Ron. This worked - although it highlighted a different issue with using the googledrive package in this way. I avoided the problem by calling the id for each file as and when needed, not all in one go.

Comment: Glad to hear that. By the way, If we answered your question, please click the accept button.  By doing so, other people in the community, who may have the same concern as you, will know that theirs can be resolved. If the accept button is unavailable to you, feel free to tell me. [How to accept answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235)